# Adding background image to div with click event.

Tags: javascript, memory

Hi everyone,

I'm building a 4x4 grid of box DIVS.  This grid is built with a loop that assigns class, ID, image date, and event listener to each div. This is part of a memory game.

```
var cards_shown = 0;
var memoryCards = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Horde Emblem',
        logo: 'horde.png',
        showing: false
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Orc Emblem',
        logo: 'orc.png',
        showing: false
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Troll Emblem',
        logo: 'troll.png',
        showing: false
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Tauren Emblem',
        logo: 'tauren.jpg',
        showing: false
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Forsaken Emblem',
        logo: 'dead.gif',
        showing: false
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Blood Elf Emblem',
        logo: 'belf.png',
        showing: false
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        name: 'Goblin Emblem',
        logo: 'goblin.png',
        showing: false
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        name: 'Pandaren Emblem',
        logo: 'panda.png',
        showing: false
    }
];

function layoutCards(){
    for (var i=0; i < 16; i++) {
        var genDiv = document.createElement('div');
        genDiv.setAttribute('id', 'memoryCard' + (i+1));
        genDiv.setAttribute('class', 'memoryCard');
        genDiv.setAttribute('data-imageId', i)

        genDiv.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            showCard(e)
        });

        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(genDiv);

        if ((i+1) % 4 == 0) {
            var newBr = document.createElement('br');
            document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(newBr);

        }
    }
}



function showCard(e){
    cards_shown += 1
    document.getElementByClassNames('memoryCard').style.backgroundImage = "url('img/" + memoryCards[i].logo + "')";
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Clicking on any of the divs should result in the appearance of an image by pulling the memoryCards.logo object information and putting it into the class or id of the div as a background style.

I'm getting a console error that reads out that document.getElementByClassNames is not a function at the showCard function and at the HTMLDivElement. line. I'm going to try using getElementByID instead and try to pass the argument in a way that takes in the modified id tag for each generated div.

It reads like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassNames is not a function
    at showCard (main.js:98)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (main.js:81)
showCard @ main.js:98
(anonymous) @ main.js:81
```

Feedback would be helpful, anonymous call functions give me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have an extra 's' at the end the end of **className**.  Change it to

```
document.getElementsByClassName('memoryCard')....
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I ended up trying something else, which I think is working out because now I'm getting a different error. 

I'm using 'e.target.style.backgroundImage' instead, but I'm getting an error that says the [i] is not defined, for some reason.